# QMessageBox segFaulting in Mainwindows slot onlclick

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia

In my qt mobile app I have a list. I have connected list clicked to a slot of main window.

```
connect(view,SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(showMessage()));

void MainWindow::showMessage()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"info","info",QMessageBox::Ok,0);
}
```

Now if i put 'QMessageBox::information(this,"info","info",QMessageBox::Ok,0);' in constructor it works.

else it gives segmentation fault.

> 0 QWidgetPrivate::setParent_sys   qwidget_simulator.cpp   207 0x0083195e
>   1   QWidget::setParent  qwidget.cpp 9985    0x00820784
>   2   QWidget::setParent  qwidget.cpp 9942    0x00820508
>   3   QFocusFramePrivate::update  qfocusframe.cpp 72  0x00c337d1
>   4   QFocusFrame::setWidget  qfocusframe.cpp 231 0x00c340aa
>   5   QS60Style::event    qs60style.cpp   3277    0x00b569e2
>   6   QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    4415    0x007d84b6
>   7   QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3817    0x007d5f0f
>   8   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    732 0x6a1fe5bc
>   9   QCoreApplication::sendEvent qcoreapplication.h  215 0x00e3ac02
>   10  QApplicationPrivate::setFocusWidget qapplication.cpp    2210    0x007d316c
>   11  QWidget::setFocus   qwidget.cpp 6288    0x00819c21
>   12  QApplication::setActiveWindow   qapplication.cpp    2590    0x007d3df8
>   13  QWidget::activateWindow qwidget_simulator.cpp   601 0x00832c02
>   14  QWidgetPrivate::show_sys    qwidget_simulator.cpp   242 0x00831af4
>   15  QWidgetPrivate::show_helper qwidget.cpp 7380    0x0081c41d
>   16  QWidget::setVisible qwidget.cpp 7594    0x0081cbbe
>   17  QDialog::setVisible qdialog.cpp 739 0x00c60f78
>   18  QWidget::show   qwidget_simulator.cpp   889 0x00833a26
>   19  QDialog::exec   qdialog.cpp 543 0x00c6060f
>   20  QMessageBoxPrivate::showOldMessageBox   qmessagebox.cpp 1906    0x00c7fdab
>   ...

this is the backtrace. what am it doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The slot has to have the same signature as the signal. You can't connect a signal taking a parameter to a slot that's expecting none. Add that `QModelIndex` parameter to `showMessage()`:

```
connect(view,SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(showMessage(QModelIndex)));

void MainWindow::showMessage(QModelIndex)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"info","info",QMessageBox::Ok,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your signal doesnt have the same signature as your slot:
clicked(QModelIndex)) = Singal.
showMessage()         = Slot.

Turn your slot to be: showMessage(QModelIndex)

Comment: don't think so. Later I changed my view from MainWindow to a form  extending Qwidget only. Now the whole thing is working without any change. Slot needs to have <= number of parameters than the signal. So I don't think that was the issue. I think I had added more than one child in central widget. Thats why messagebox was segfaulting on setparent.